# How to convert the message in to a json object

Tags: json, node.js

I am using a client program called fire packets to fire some hexadecimal data on to a server program in which the server listening on a specified port. The server program works well and it receives the message from the client but need to convert the message into a json object in which results undefined when tried can any one please tell me how to do the conversion of the message into json object. Will attach the server program below,

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var fs = require('fs');
server.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Error:" + err.stack);
    server.close();
});
server.on("message", function(msg, rinfo) {
    console.log("server got the message :" + msg + "from" + rinfo.address + "from the port" + rinfo.port);
    fs.writeFile("packet.txt", msg.toString(), 'utf-8', function(err) {
        //var jsonmess=JSON.parse(msg);
        //console.log(jsonmess);
        console.log("written on packet");
    });
});
server.on("listening", function() {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log("Server listening on:" + address.address + "on the port:" + address.port);
});
server.bind(5432);
```

The message i send to through the client is
4500005100060000801116FB75610CFACF47D1F8501E5014003DD5C383051632426347010101020AC252F131AB52F131AB0776956F2CC65619000002CC0000000000000800005FFF970F07660001080100000032C8
 When i stringify the JSON object the data has been shown as

[131,5,22,50,66,99,71,1,1,1,2,10,194,82,241,49,171,82,241,49,171,7,118,149,111,44,198,86,25,0,0,2,204,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,95,255,151,15,7,102,0,1,8,1,0,0,0,50,200]

How can i get the exact value that has been send through the client on a server json object

Comment: I think you're looking for `JSON.stringify()` not `JSON.parse()`, the latter is for decoding.

Comment: Without knowing what the message looks like it's difficult to determine what should happen.

Comment: I tried with JSON.stringfy instead of JSON.parse it works perfect. Tanks Ben.